# Modify Case Query to not count NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The query below is counting 'defects' in data for me, meaning any time when the EncounterID matches but other columns do not. How can I modify the query to not include any 'defects' caused by NULL values?

```
SELECT FacilityCode,
       AdmitDate,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN NumFirstName <> 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DifferentFirstNames,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN NumLastName <> 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DifferentLastNames,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN NumPhone <> 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DifferentPhone,
       'Defect' Label
FROM   (SELECT EncounterId,
               FacilityCode,
               AdmitDate,
               COUNT(*)                           AS Num,
               COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(FirstName, 4)) AS NumFirstName,
               COUNT(DISTINCT LastName)           AS NumLastName,
               COUNT(DISTINCT Phone)              AS NumPhone,
        FROM   [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]
        GROUP  BY EncounterId,
                  facilitycode,
                  AdmitDate) e
GROUP  BY FacilityCode,
          AdmitDate;
```

Here is what the current situation looks like:

Sample Data:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     FirstName              LastName
BOHG             7-1-15        Justin                 Kelley
BOHG             7-1-15        Justin                 NULL
AARD             7-1-15        James                  Smith
AARD             7-1-15        James                  Smith
```

Sample Output:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     DifferentFirstNames    DifferentLastNames
BOHG             7-1-15        0                      1
AARD             7-1-15        0                      0
```

I would like to ignore the first last name change because it is NULL and have all 0s in the output (I only care if there is a change such as Kelley changing to Kelly):

Desired Output:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     DifferentFirstNames    DifferentLastNames
BOHG             7-1-15        0                      0
AARD             7-1-15        0                      0
```

Comment: Are all columns showing null values included in count or just Num perhaps? distinct field name should exclude NULLs when counting... * will not.  Some sample data and expected results would help us visualize your issue. also could the count be > 1 based on group by and data thus some may show 0 or act like null when infact it's because 2 records with the same encounterId, facilityCode andd admitdate exist?

Comment: @xQbert See above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de284/8/0) gives you the results you asked for... but I'm not sure it will work all the time.  I'm not sure why your approach wouldn't work All I did was eliminate the errors on your code and remove unneeded fields... the counts work as expected.

```
SELECT FacilityCode,
       AdmitDate,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN NumFirstName <> 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DifferentFirstNames,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN NumLastName <> 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DifferentLastNames
FROM   (SELECT 
               FacilityCode,
               AdmitDate,
               COUNT(*)                           AS Num,
               COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(FirstName, 4)) AS NumFirstName,
               COUNT(DISTINCT LastName)           AS NumLastName
        FROM  [tbFCCDefectReport]
        GROUP  BY facilitycode,
                  AdmitDate) e
GROUP  BY FacilityCode,
          AdmitDate;
```

There may be two other ways that offer better scaling with this query.

One way is to generate two different sets of data one "Before" one "After" but I don't know how to relate the data without the keys of the table.

something like

```
SELECT A.Key, 
sum(case when (coalesce(Before.Field1,'') = coalesce(After.Field1,'') OR After.Field1 is null) then 0 else 1 end) as countField1Difference,
sum(case when coalesce(Before.Field2,'') = coalesce(After.Field2,'') OR After.Field2 is null) then 0 else 1 end) as countField2Difference
FROM TableName Before
LEFT JOIN TableName After
 on A.Key = B.Key
and B.Bal = 'Something which denotes it as the After set'
and A.Val = 'something which denotes it as the Before set'
GROUP BY A.Key
```

The coalesce handles the null values allowing the string compairison to report

alternatively you could use

```
Select * from tableName where B.Val = 'something denoting it's the before value'
EXCEPT
Select * from tableName where B.Val = 'something denoting it's the after value'
```

However this shows any difference as an entire difference not column by column